# Is there a way to distinguish between source of voice in a telephonic call

Tags: android, kotlin

I've a telephonic calls recorder app that work with the below code:

```
var IS_SERVICE_RUNNING = false

class AudioService : Service(), MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {

    lateinit var context: Context
    private var mRecorder: MediaRecorder? = null
    //setting maximum file size to be recorded
    private val Audio_MAX_FILE_SIZE: Long = 1000000//1Mb

    private var mOutputFile: File? = null
    private var mStartTime: Long = 0

    private val outputFile: File
        get() {
            val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMdd_HHmm", Locale.US)
            return File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), //  Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, //    context.filesDir, //
                    //  .absolutePath.toString()
                    "call_"  // "/Voice Recorder/RECORDING_"
                            + dateFormat.format(Date())
                            + ".m4a")
        }

    override fun onInfo(mr: MediaRecorder?, what: Int, extra: Int) {
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_REACHED) {
             stopRecording(true)
        }
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        Toast.makeText(context,"started recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        val downloadIntent = Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, downloadIntent, 0)

        val notification = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                Notification.Builder(context, NotificationService.CHANNEL_ID)
            } else {
                Notification.Builder(context)
            }.apply {
                setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_error_black_24dp)
                setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                setAutoCancel(true)
                setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.recording_title))
                setStyle(Notification.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(resources.getString(R.string.recording_body)))
                setContentText(resources.getString(R.string.recording_body))
            }.build()

        val nManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            // Start foreground service.
            startForeground(1, notification);
        } else {
            nManager.notify(1, notification)
        }

        mRecorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            // reset()
        }
        mRecorder!!.setOnInfoListener(this)

        mOutputFile = outputFile
        mOutputFile!!.parentFile.mkdirs()

        mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mRecorder!!.apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            //  setMaxFileSize(Audio_MAX_FILE_SIZE)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
            // setOutputFile(mFileName)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.HE_AAC)
            setAudioEncodingBitRate(48000)
            setAudioSamplingRate(16000)
            setOutputFile(mOutputFile!!.absolutePath)
        }

        try {
            mRecorder!!.prepare()
            mRecorder!!.start()
        } catch (ise: IllegalStateException) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error 1 $ise ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } catch (ioe: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error 2 $ioe ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        return Service.START_STICKY
    }

    private fun stopRecording(saveFile: Boolean) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"stopped recording ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        mRecorder!!.apply {
            stop()
            reset()
            release()
        }
        mRecorder = null
        mStartTime = 0
        if (!saveFile && mOutputFile != null) {
            mOutputFile!!.delete()
        }

        // Stop foreground service and remove the notification.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            stopForeground(false)
        } else stopSelf()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
      //  Toast.makeText(context,"service destroyed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        stopRecording(true)
    }
}
```

That is started from the below code:

```
class PhoneStateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0)
        val record_calls = prefs!!.getBoolean("recordCalls", false)
        val service = Intent(context, AudioService::class.java)

        val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)

        when(state){
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING -> {
                            }
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                            if (record_calls) {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    context.startForegroundService(service)
                                } else context.startService(service)
                            }
            }
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE -> {
                if (IS_SERVICE_RUNNING) context.stopService(service)
            }
            else -> Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to recognize if the voice heard is from my device or from the other person person on the line, so I can decide if I need to filter both sides talks or one side call only (the other one talks)!

Comment: make your AI for this - [it is possible](https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/04/looking-to-listen-audio-visual-speech.html) (edit: oh sorry it's for audio-visual - stil you can try to build some AI for this)

Comment: It's been a while since I was working with this sort of stuff, but why would you expect to get any downlink audio when using `AudioSource.MIC`?

Comment: My point was that `AudioSource.MIC` means you want to record from the microphone. I see no reason why that would give you any voicecall downlink audio (i.e. what the person on the far end is saying). Unless you're in speakerphone mode, in which case the microphone might pick up some of the audio coming through the loudspeaker.

Comment: There are dedicated audiosources for voicecall recording. See the AudioSource documentation.